# Why am I being asked to Restart System even though I have Canonical Livepatch?

Tags: apt, updates, canonical-livepatch

I'm confused about when I need to do system restarts even though I have Canonical Livepatch on Ubunut 20.04LTS Server

```
$ sudo canonical-livepatch status --verbose
last check: 22 minutes ago
kernel: 5.4.0-29.33-generic
server check-in: succeeded
patch state: ✓ no livepatches needed for this kernel yet
client version: 9.5.5
architecture: x86_64
cpu model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1230 V2 @ 3.30GHz
boot time: 3 weeks ago
```

Logging in gave me

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-29-generic x86_64)
62 updates can be installed immediately.
38 of these updates are security updates
```

So I did the usual

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

but now I get 
`*** System restart required ***`

and

```
$ cat /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
linux-image-5.4.0-33-generic
linux-base
```

So do I need to restart and if so why? Isn't Livepatch meant to take care of critical Kernel patches. Or am I misunderstanding what `linux-image` and `linux-base` are?

My understanding is that Livepatch exists so we don't need to restart. How do I avoid this situation while still doing the security updates.

Comment: The reboot required message is triggered by the presence of the file `/var/run/reboot-required`. That file is usually created by upgrading various packages. You can see which one(s) triggered the reboot request by looking inside `/var/run/reboot-required.pkgs`. That might give you an indication why it's asking for a reboot even with livepatch installed and configured.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you managed to find an answer for this, but as I was myself struggling with the same question, I did some research.
Security updates are rated from negligible to critical level (there are 5 rating levels).
You can check the rating level of each update, running this command:

```
xargs apt-get changelog < /var/run/reboot-required.pkgs
```

This will output the whole "history" (changelog) of each package (press "q" to navigate between each listed package) listed in the `reboot-required.pkgs` file.
The most recent update is located at the top of the list. At the right side of each update, you should see an `urgency=` flag that states its rating.
The "critical" rated updates should be automatically applied to the kernel by the Livepatch module, so as to avoid having to reboot the server.

Without the Livepatch module, you would be forced to reboot your server in order to apply the security patch to the kernel.

Lastly, if you want to check if there are services that need to be restarted following the system update, install the `needestart` package `sudo apt-get install needrestart` and then run `sudo needrestart`.
This will show you the services that need to be restarted, and give the possibility to restart them right away!

So long story short, you don't need to reboot your server! ;-)